# Making one of the threads to wait for least possible (almost zero) time

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl

There is a list. Two types of threads are operating on the list (after exclusive access to list as STL containers are NOT thread safe)

- Adder threads: Items are being added to list by multiple threads.
- Processor thread: Items from list are being processed and deleted one by one, by *a thread.*

**Problem:** When processor thread wants to access the list it should get quickest access (even if other adder threads are already waiting to access list, processor thread should be given highest priority). Ideally I am expecting almost no wait.

1. Will change is thread priority help solving this?
2. Is there any algorithmic solution to this (May be alternative approaches etc.) ?

(By the way the solution could be specific to Windows operating system as well, if at all it solves the problem)

Comment: What if the list is empty and there is nothing for the processor thread to do? Should it still get instant access to the thread? Or do you want it to wait until there is something or it to do?

Comment: Even if its empty its fine to get instant access by processor thread. The thread may just return. But under no circumstance the thread should wait.

Comment: I suggest you use locks. Such that the Adder threads will lock the list. It will then hold on to the list until its done, once its done the lock should be passed on to the Processor thread. Processor thread will be in charge of the list until its done then it can unlock the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't dig into threads yet but what about using two mutexes for this?
One `adder_queue` mutex and one mutex `access`.

In the adder code do

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> queue_lock(adder_queue);
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> access_lock(access);
// add operation
```

And the processor thread can perform

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> access_lock(access);
// process operation
```

The adder threads should now wait for `adder_queue` mutex before trying to lock `access` and thus the processor thread should always be next after the operation that is currently happening.

Comment: That's not really the behavior the OP is asking for (zero blocking). It might be what the OP *needs*, but if so, the answer should explain why.

Comment: He asked for the process thread to have priority over waiting adder threads. Zero blocking was the "ideal" case. (Which is -I guess- impossible without a severe risk (with respect to thread saftey).)

Comment: Yes this is good idea. Cannot achieve zero wait but by having two locks (double for adder and single for processor) processor thread always can be made to stay ahead of all adders threads.